# Disagree with a flag...where?

Tags: support, flags

Disagree = do nothing?  What's the button for.

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that disagreeing with a flag did not create another flag.  Seems like bad design to me.

Comment: @MatthewRead It doesn't make another flag; it gives us a note beneath the original flag saying "Deemed invalid by <username>", and I think it also moves the flag to the bottom of the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See that middle option that says invalid flag?  You can choose that if you disagree.

[image: freehand circle]

Comment: nope, it blended in too well